# JSP Character Encoding

Tags: jsp, utf-8

i have a problem with character encoding in my jsp file.
Im using data out of a database and the database got the data
from a xml file.

- char encoding of xml-file is utf-8
- char encoding of database is utf-8
- char encoding of jsp is utf-8

  ```
  <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
  <%@page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

  <head>
      <link href="../css/movies.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
      <title>Movies</title>
  </head>

  <body>
      <div id="wrapper">

          <br></br>
          <h2 id="title">Movies</h2>
          <br></br>

          <ul>
              <c:forEach var="movie" items="${requestScope.movies}">
                  <li id="listElement"><a class="listElementLink" href="../servlets/SingleMovieServlet?id=${movie.movieID}">${movie.title}</a></li>
              </c:forEach>
          </ul>
      </div>
  </body>
  </html>
  ```

The output doesnt seem to be utf-8 because i get for example this title:

```
KÃ¶nigskinder
```

This should be:

```
 Königskinder
```

Also i have the problem that if i have a title like this:

```
Pirates of the Caribbean: Dead Man&apos;s Chest
```

The output is just:

```
s Chest
```

How can i get my encoding working?

Comment: you need to check at each level if characters are right. Check in xml first when it is generated, then check in the database and then check final browser display.

Comment: ... and your taglib encoding

Comment: i see now in my database, that the data arent correctly imported! The title "Pirates of the Caribbean: Dead Man&apos;s Chest" gets imported into the database as "s Chest" but the xml file is utf-8 (without BOM) and the database is also utf-8

Comment: This is not utf-8 issue. This is xml characters escaping issue. In your code, you need to convert these escaping characters into its proper format before you store them in database. **ie:** converting `&apos` into '